# When I use the Pumping Lemma from Automata Theory, what are my restrictions for "i"?

Tags: automata, regular-language, pumping-lemma

The pumping lemma says:
Let L be a regular language. Then there exists an integer p ≥ 1   such that every string w in L of length at least p can be written as s = xyz, satisfying the following conditions:

```
|y| ≥ 1 
|xy| ≤ p 
(∀i≥0 ) (z = xy^i z∈L)
```

When we use the pumping lemma to prove that a language cannot be regular, there's this part where we choose an 'i' from the natural numbers for the proof. I want to ask, is there another restriction on 'i' ? Can I make 'i' dependant on p by saying "Let i = 2p" or something like that? Or if we know that we can present s as s=xyz, can I make i dependant on the length of x |x|=t or the length of y |y|=l and say "Let i = 2t" or "Let i =2l" ? Sorry if that's a stupid question

Edit:
An example problem where I think I would need to do that is following:
Prove that the language is not regular: L={ $a^{n}$$b^{m}$ |n divides m}

To solve this I set s to be s =$a^{p}$$b^{2p}$  ,|s|=3p>=p and p divides 2p, so we have that s is in L.
Then I divide the string into s=xyz, and note that because of the condition |xy|<=p, xy consists only of a's. I set the length of x |x|=t and the length of y |y|=l and my string has the form:
s=$a^{l}$$a^{t}$$a^{p-l-t}$$b^{2p}$ .
Then I have that ∀i≥0, s' = x$y^{i}$z must be from L, so aim to choose an 'i' resulting in contradiction.
I have that il+t+p-l-t≤2p ( so that n divides m ),
which results in p+l(i-1)≤2p, and if I choose i=p+1 the condition is broken, because now p+l(p+1-1)≤2p is no longer true, because l is at least one and thus the left side is bigger, so we get a contradiction

I am not sure if this is correct because I am quite new in this subject, so any critique and feedback is welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: You certainly can, with a caveat that $p$ and $x, y, z$ may not be uniquely determined - but you can always say, because they *exist*, settle on one possible example of $p, x, y, z$ and start from there. However, I can see how people could get the argument wrong for other reasons, so I wonder if you have a *particular* proof in mind, for which you want to check if it is correct, rather than asking a general question. (It may turn out that the proof is wrong not because $i$ was chosen as a function of. say $p$, but for other reasons!)

Comment: (Just to be clear, this is not a *restriction* on $i$ - the pumping lemma says that $xy^iz\in L$ *for every $i$*" - but it is *you* who chooses a particularly ghastly $i$ for which $xy^iz$ is obviously not in $L$, thereby reaching a contradiction.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop I added the problem I was refering to and my "solution", I am not sure it is correct though

Comment: Yep, the idea is absolutely correct. Technical detail, I think knowing $l\ge 1$, $p+l(i-1)\le 2p$ becomes provably false only when $i>p+1$ so I would choose $i=p+2$. Otherwise it is all ok. Well done. (If we want to nitpick, you should also state what's the meaning of the expression $p+l(i-1)$ - namely you will have *that many* $a$'s followed by $2p$ $b$'s in the word in $L$, so if we manage to make more $a$'s than $b$'s - that word is certainly not in $L$. Contradiction!)

Comment: Oh yeah, i=p+1 doesn't work but p+2 does. Nitpicking is always good becaue my lector does it, so I will include that in my formal proof haha. Thank u so much, have a great day :)